# T-SQL Modify Procedure Definition using DDLTrigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Database Trigger on my Database that Audits a Procedure using the EventData when the Procedure is Created/Altered.

I would like to know if there is any way that I can Modify the Procedure Definition by "SlipStreaming" a Comment Line to the End of the Procedure Definition? without Having to : Disable the Trigger, Creating Dynamic SQL String from DDL Definition in EVENTDATA, Appending the relevant Comment line to Dynamic SQL, execute the Dynimc SQL to Update proc, Then enable Trigger again...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to disable the trigger, because SQL Server by default will not allow a trigger to trigger itself (this is governed by the `RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` database option, which by default is off). So you can make a DDL modification from a trigger without fear of triggering yourself -- but what you do want to do is verify that you are not being triggered by another trigger, as that can cause loops. For that, use `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL`.

The following is a little rough around the edges, but it should get you started. In particular, you will probably want to customize the comment. Also, detecting if the modification mark is already present is iffy (but you may not need it if you don't mind stacking comments). You may consider adding/changing an [extended property](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms190243) on the stored procedure instead of textually modifying it.

```
AFTER CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE
AS
BEGIN
    SET ARITHABORT ON;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1 RETURN;

    PRINT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), EVENTDATA());

    DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(128);
    SET @DatabaseName = EVENTDATA().value(
        '(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(128)'
    );
    DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(128);
    SET @Schema = EVENTDATA().value(
        '(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(128)'
    );
    DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(128);
    SET @Name = EVENTDATA().value(
        '(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(128)'
    );

    DECLARE @Definition NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @Definition = 
        OBJECT_DEFINITION(
            OBJECT_ID(
                QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + '.' + 
                QUOTENAME(@Schema) + '.' + 
                QUOTENAME(@Name),
                'P'
            )
        )
    ;
    SELECT @Definition = STUFF(
        @Definition, 
        CHARINDEX('CREATE', @Definition), 
        LEN('CREATE'), 
        'ALTER'
    );

    IF @Definition NOT LIKE '%--Hacked by Chinese' BEGIN;
        SET @Definition += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '--Hacked by Chinese';
        EXEC (@Definition);
    END;
END;
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER [TR_TweakStoredProcedures] ON DATABASE
```